# QListWidget color-alternated rows on empty area

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I've been trying to copy my QTreeView style/behavior to my QListWidget. Everything works fine except when trying to apply that style: `paint-alternating-row-colors-for-empty-area` which, in a way, make sense because that tag should only be supported by QTreeView.

Do you guys know a good way to re-implement that behavior?
Maybe I can tweak my QAbstractItemView? Or try to go with a QListView + Custom model?

Please find enclosed what it's look like on my QTreeView:
[image: QTreeView lookk]

And here is my current QListWidget:

[image]

And here is the Style Sheet I used on both:

```
QListWidget,
QTreeView
{
    border: 0px;
    color: white;
    paint-alternating-row-colors-for-empty-area: 1;
    background-color: #292929;
    alternate-background-color: #2C2C2C;
}
```

Edit:
So, I know that I can replace my QListWidget by another QTreeView, but the thing is, would I be able to get custom item like that using a QTreeView? [image]

Comment: Why don't you use `QTreeView` for both? Just set the `rootIsDecorated` property to false and it will behave like a list.

Comment: I've used ui->treeView->setStyleSheet("{paint-alternating-row-colors-for-empty-area:1; }"); and it works.

Comment: Yeah I know it's working with the QTreeView, just wondering if I would be able to reproduce that kind of items with or should I stick with a QListWidget and try to find a workaround.
here is what I want to achieve: [Custom Item](http://imgur.com/7BkoPXS).

Comment: have you figure that out?

Comment: @Bear Not really, I went on using a QTreeWidget with a custom QAbstractItemDelegate of mine... Not ideal, but it is the only way I've found to do the alternate colours.

Comment: i see... in android i usually create a custom `layout` and assign it to `TreeView` to view for each row, and then pass the date as item to view. (based on how i designed my layout and information required to display), however, i decided to do the same thing in Qt, but i'm not sure if it's possible in Qt.

Comment: Well it is basically what I've done, except than instead of having a custom layout - I actually have my delegate that draws it (the custom layout) for me. Not sure how to use a .UI file with a delegate tho.